# Does service fabric actor model allow throttling? If not, how to make one?

Tags: actor, azure-service-fabric

Here is my scenario using service fabric cluster:

1. One actor instance per 1 customer.
2. Actor instance id is customer id. So this actor is my customer actor.
3. The customer actor implements a workflow that has n number of steps.
4. Lets say, at step m (of n steps), this actor needs to talk to external system (E).
5. System E does not allow more than x number of clients at any given time.
6. I have 100,000 customer actor instances at any given time.
7. Because of external system (E), I need to throttle my customer actors to x at step m.
8. After step m (with throttling set at x), I want to be back to full potential of actor model again.

Here are my questions:

1. Does service fabric cluster actor model provide any throttling mechanism? With that throttling mechanism, how would my scenario change?
2. If there is no out-of-box solution for throttling in actor model, how would I go about creating one?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd use some kind of Queue to deal with load bursts. You could (for instance) add a Service between the Actor and system E that enqueues messages from the Actors, and then processes them in the background, using throttling there.

Actors and their callers won't need to know about any throttling. And it decouples the Actors from system E.

Comment: Please see my comment to Vaclav and let me know if that is a viable option.

Comment: Some words of caution, because of the turn based access model and RPC style communication, waiting inside an Actor also causes the callers to wait (slowing down the whole system). And during that wait other operations don't execute. (including timers & reminders)
Also, the Statemanager within the Actor doesn't work well when accessed from multiple concurrent threads. So maintaining how many concurrent requests are executing is hard. I think a Service is more suitable for this purpose.

Comment: Have a look at (https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/blob/master/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/BrokerService.cs) for inspiration on how to enqueue and background process incoming messages.

Comment: I was planning to use reminder to quickly release the control back to the caller for scalability. With service fabric 5.2.207 release, there is new ReliableConcurrentQueue. Does not this address concurrency issues?

Answer (score 0):

No there's nothing like that built in. If your system E can only handle x clients, and you have y > x actors, then your actors can simply try to talk to E at step m, and if E is at capacity, back-off and try again later. What other sort of throttling are you hoping for?

Comment: I thought of extracting step m into its own actor (say SystemEActor), which will be responsible for communicating with System E. When customer actor creates SystemEActor at step m, I was hoping for a way to throttle SystemEActor without additional coding. But it appears the SystemEActor can become throttling actor by keeping state of how many concurrent requests are executing at any moment. If the capacity is full, it should simply wait. Otherwise it can communicate with System E as usual. The next question is how to let objects go out of memory while waiting. Probably use reminders?